# Make a letter thinner with Inkscape

Tags: vector, inkscape, drawing

I have different logos I have to redraw. I use Inkscape. I find a letter that is similar than the original. But the original has thinner lines. If I Path > Object to Path, this converts the line of each letter in two lines. Is there a way to avoid that. I mean, is there a way to convert the original lines of each letter to a different thickness all together and with a numeric precise value?

[image]

Comment: No time to write a decent answer, now. Have you tried to [inset](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Editing.html) the path? See also [here](http://www.ryanlerch.org/blog/inkscape-path-manipulation-tutorial-insetting-and-outsetting-paths/).

Comment: Yes, it works. It would be great if I could make the inset with numbers to make all the letters inset exactly the same. Do you know if there is a way to do that?

Comment: I think that such a functionality would be interesting but in my opinion at the moment is not available. Perhaps you can [request](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/inkscape) to Inkscape team to add this feature. Meanwhile, if inset had worked, you can write your own answer.

Comment: @Paolo: thank you. You should put your comment as an answer

Answer (score 8):

1. give your text a **stroke**
2. convert the **stroke to path**
3. perform **Break Apart** path operation, Reduce the opacity to 25(so that the overlapping paths could be identified)
4. **Remove** unwanted parts(the outer and lighter parts)
5. for complex paths like 'A', 'O' remove the innermost and outermost path.
6. select all the other paths and **combine** them(perform combine path operation) and bring the opacity back to 100

[image: Procedure to make texts thin]
you can use this method to make texts thin or thick(by discarding the inner paths and keeping the outer paths)

you can also use this method to draw 2 concentric shapes with uniform distance between them(i always use this method rather than uniform scaling, it does not produce the result you expect if all sides of the shape is not the same and its much easier than manual scaling)

Comment: removing unwanted parts doesn't work for me, the character just gets deformed